# Reading a NSInputStream produces a -1 bytes available error

Tags: swift, foundation, nsinputstream

I'm trying to do some simple encoding using `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream`:

```
import Foundation

let path = "/Users/johni/desktop/a" // holds "123456789abcdef"
var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
var inp: NSInputStream = NSInputStream(data: data)
println(data.length) // returns 15
println(inp.hasBytesAvailable) // returns false
```

I'm receiving a `-1` from the read method, meaning that it has no bytes available, why does this happen?

I have also have tried initializing the `NSInputStream` directly with the `fileAtPath` initializer and got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an input stream until you open it.

```
inp.open()
inp.hasBytesAvailable //returns true
```